# Async function on other js files always return undefined, but the function run

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

i have an async function which return 1 or 0 value on a js file, this it the code

```
checkAuthentication: async function (client) {
        //search redis
        //get value key "token"
        try{
            var tempValue, tempErr

            client.get("token", async (err, value) => {
                tempValue = value
                tempErr = err
                if (tempErr) { // kalo gk ada di redis
                    console.log(tempErr) 
                    return 0
                }
                if (tempValue !== null) {//ADA DI REDIS
                    var start = new Date()
                    var responseRedis = JSON.parse(tempValue)
                    // console.log('this is old data' + responseRedis.accessToken)
    
                    var end = (new Date() - start)
                    console.info('Execution time: %d ms', end)
                    
                    jwt.verify(responseRedis.accessToken, accessTokenSecret, function (err, decoded) {//check if token expired or not
                        if (err) {//TOKEN EXPIRED
                            console.log(err)
                            return 0
                        } else {//TOKEN TIDAK EXPIRED
                            //tuker token jd refreshesh token
                            const newRefreshToken = jwt.sign({ username: decoded.user_name }, accessTokenSecret, { expiresIn: '24h' });
                            var data_send_redis = JSON.stringify({
                                "accessToken": newRefreshToken,
                            });
                            //store to redis 
                            // console.log('this is  new data' + data_send_redis)
                            client.setex("token", 600, data_send_redis);
                            return 1
                        }
                    });
                } else { //GK ADA DI REDIS TOKENYA
                    //LOG OUT
                    console.log('token not found')
                    return 0
                }
            })
        }catch (err){
            console.log(err)
            return 0
        }
    }
```

in the other hand i trying to get the value in a variable named a in other js files

```
var a = await model_auth_token.checkAuthentication(client)
console.log('hasil check auth : return ' + a)
if(a == 0){
    client.del('token', function(err, response) {
        if (response == 1) {
           console.log("Deleted Successfully!")
        } else{
         console.log("Fail to Delete")
         console.log(err)
        }
     });
     res.redirect('/panel/panel_login')
     return
}
```

whenever i do console log result always shows undefined, i already add await or then on the function, but the console log result always shows undefined

Answer (score 1):

You are returning from a .then or .catch callback, which is a function.

You need to wrap the client.get block in a Promise:

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... });
```

Then, use `resolve()` to 'succeed', and `reject()` to 'fail'.